# Subgraph access control

Tags: neo4j, controls, subgraph

In the official Documentation (3.1: http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/subgraph-access-control/)
It is said

"For example, a user can be allowed to read, but not write, nodes labelled with Employee and relationships of type REPORTS_TO"

But nowhere it's written in this page and others how to do it.
With the "call dbms.procedures()" we can see many more function in the enterprise edition but nothing about defining this Subgraph control

We think on changing the an enterprise edition, but if we are sure to be able to do that. 
Can anyone explain me or gives me the address of the relevant documentation

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is all right there. Note the first sentence:

> Through the use of **user-defined procedures** and **custom roles**, an
>   administrator may restrict a user’s access and subsequent actions to
>   specified portions of the graph.

The approach seems to be, for users without write permission, create roles for them as appropriate, then create (or use existing) user-defined procedures to do what operations they are allowed to do. Then configure the permissions of the procedures to the appropriate level, and associate the roles of the procedures (by modifying `dbms.security.procedures.roles`) with the roles you previously created. This allows the procedures you created to be executed by the roles you associated it with.

For example, given an HR user, who does not have write permissions, you could create a procedure to create or delete a :REPORTS_TO relationship between :Employee nodes. The procedure would need to be set to mode=WRITE since it needs write access. This would normally not be executable by this HR user, since they don't have write permissions.

But if you created a role, say 'hr', and added that role to this user, and set the procedure to be accessible by the hr role in `dbms.security.procedures.roles`, then the hr user could execute this procedure, and it would perform the necessary write operations.

In summary, Neo4j's subgraph access control isn't defined on the nodes or labels themselves, nor does it apply when executing write statements in Cypher. This access control is specific to user-defined procedures, and allows users with certain roles (where that role is associated with those procedures) to execute those procedures even if they normally would not be able to due to their access level.

EDIT

One final thing that could work for you...Neo4j has a means of registering [transaction event handlers](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/#transactions-events) that can perform checking and logic on a transaction in progress, and reject if some criteria are not met. I would assume you could get a user's roles here, and probably check the transaction for writer operations on certain labels. Odd that this wasn't referenced in the securing the subgraph section of the documentation. I haven't tried this approach myself (I'll try my own testing later) so I'm not sure if it will fulfill what you need, but it's worth a look.

UPDATE:

It's been awhile, but we do have a more comprehensive means of access control coming to the upcoming Neo4j 4.0.

4.0 will include schema-based security, full ability to define, per user and role, the ability to grant or deny various levels of permissions (read, write, traverse, and more) for nodes and relationships of specific types. So for example you can have various roles that only have visibility on certain kinds of nodes, or are specifically denied visibility on others. You can also restrict whether certain nodes can be traversed through at all.

This should fulfill the needs of everyone who has been waiting for a more comprehensive security and access solution in Neo4j.

Here's the [Neo4j 4.0 MR2 documentation](https://neo4j.com/wp-content/themes/neo4jweb/assets/images/Neo4j_EE_4.0_MR2_Doc.pdf), more to come as we approach the official 4.0 release!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First I thought it was something else this procedure feature.
I relaized what you explain really later as it wasn't at all what we expected. 
It's really strange to have created a so difficult system to put in place (coding java/creating jar, deploying, restarting server)
We were searching something more dynamic, not prehistoric, we may re-code our graph layer using OrientDB
BTW, thanks again!

Comment: I added one possible alternative with transaction handlers, that may work for you as well.

Comment: Updated to mention the new security and access control features of the upcoming Neo4j 4.0 release.